# login to third party website using the credentials in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to login to a third party website using credentials.
Here is the code which I am using got through stackoverflow, but its redirecting to login page I think session is not storing how to store the session

```
    //The URL of the Login Form of the website
    String urlSignin = "https://www.grouprevmax.com/WebMARDSV2/RevenueCaterSuper/RevenueManager.aspx";

    //The action URL of the Login Form of the website on Submit
    String urlLogin = "https://www.grouprevmax.com/WebMARDSV2/RevenueCaterSuper/RevenueManager.aspx";

    //Initializes the Uri object of the URLs
    Uri uriSignin = new Uri(urlSignin);
    Uri uriLogin = new Uri(urlLogin);

    //Hashtable to store the form details
    Hashtable formData = new Hashtable();
    formData.Add("UTC", new Hashtable());
    formData.Add("txtUserName", new Hashtable());
    formData.Add("txtPassword", new Hashtable());

    ((Hashtable)formData["UTC"])["value"] = -330;
    ((Hashtable)formData["txtUserName"])["value"] = username;
    ((Hashtable)formData["txtPassword"])["value"] = password;

    //Initializing the data for the post action
    String postData = "";

    foreach (string name in formData.Keys)
    {
        postData += "&" + name + "=" + ((Hashtable)formData[name])["value"];
    }
    postData = postData.Substring(1);

    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

    HttpWebRequest webReq;
    HttpWebResponse webResp;

    //To store the cookies of the response objects to be used for the next request
    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

    String responseString = "";

    try
    {
        //Getting response for the Signin page  
        webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlSignin);
        webResp = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();

        //Storing response cookies to be used in the next request
        cookies.Add(webResp.Cookies);

        //Storing ASPSESSION cookie that appears in the Response header Set-Cookie to be used in the next request
        string sessionCookie = webResp.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
        responseString = new StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        string respCookie = sessionCookie.Substring(0, sessionCookie.IndexOf(';'));
        char[] separator = { '=' };
        string[] cookieValues = respCookie.Split(separator);
        cookies.Add(new Cookie(cookieValues[0], cookieValues[1], "/", "www.grouprevmax.com"));

        //Initializing the request object for log in
        webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlLogin);
        webReq.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        webReq.Referer = urlSignin;
        webReq.KeepAlive = true;
        webReq.Method = "POST";
        webReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
        webReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        webReq.CookieContainer = cookies;
        webReq.Timeout = 30000;
        webReq.ReadWriteTimeout = 60000;



        //Get the response for the request to log in
        //PROBLEM OCCURS HERE - THE CODE DOES NOT EXECUTE FURTHER
        webReq.GetRequestStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        webReq.GetRequestStream().Close();
        webResp = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();
        responseString = new StreamReader(webResp.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        webResp.Close();
        return responseString;
```

Comment: Try using Fiddler to review the exchange with the web server. This helps you diagnose the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `CookieContainer` with the cookies you gathered from the `webResp`.

```
cookies.Add(webResp.Cookies);
```

You should *not* process the cookies as you are below that. Simply setting the `CookieContainer` on the new request is sufficient.

```
webReq.CookieContainer = cookies;
```

Comment: i ha changed the code like this           webReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
            webReq.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            cookies.Add(webResp.Cookies);
           // webReq.CookieContainer = cookies;
            webReq.Timeout = 30000;
            webReq.ReadWriteTimeout = 60000; but still its not working

Answer (score 0):

In Third party websites , they may passing the credentials with some dynamic parameters which they generated when we loading the page . So before that analyze that website using `firebug` or `fiddler`  and identify what are the parameters they passing while login and try to pass those parameters . This way may help you